# Copy numbers from 1 sheet to multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, reference, copy

Say I have 1000 serial numbers in sheet 1 and I created 1000 different sheets.

I wanna refer to sheet 1 and copy every single serial number to the 1000 sheets respectively, so that every sheet have different one serial number.  Could anyone advise how to do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Loop through the numbers and write to new sheets seems a possibility. Or you could duplicate the sheet and delete the extra numbers...

Comment: Thank you sir! Could you show me the VBA codes?

Comment: This is not a free code writing service, show some effort and people will help. You asked for advice and I gave you that., may not be the best though and others may have better suggestions. But you now want VBa but did not even tag it on your question.

Comment: Sub test()
count = Worksheets.count
For i = 1 To count

Worksheets(1 + i).Range("A5").Value = Worksheets("Reference").range("B(4 + i)").Value
Next
End Sub

*## Copy data from worksheet 1(Reference)(B5, B6, B7... cells) to all other sheets A5 cell*

PS I am new to VBA and spent some time writing the above codes. I got error 1004, any syntax wrong? Thank you!!